# Software for system backup, with differential backups and bootable restorations

Tags: windows-7, backup, bootable-media, incremental-backup

> **Reminder:** I do understand that we have tens and perhaps over a hundred of questions associated with the backup and community faqs are being written for that but I am asking a different question. If you are going to comment TL;DR then please do read first before closing this question

I am asking if there is recommendation for software that does all below:

1. Backups of the complete windows installation and allows restoration even if the current machine becomes unbootable (i.e. either allows booting from a DVD/USB drive and then restore from network, or booting from USB media)
2. Incremental backup possible and I am able to choose a particular snapshot of the system (measured in the incremental frequency. I do want to be able to restore to each possible snapshot if possible).
3. Individual file accessible without much hassle, for example, Ghost explorer-esque interface would be excellent.

System: Windows 7 64-bit Home premium & Ultimate.

Free software or freeware suggestions greatly appreciated as I need to do that for multiple family machines.

Comment: @Thiago M. Okay. Changed. It's colloquial in my language, if it mattered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EASEUS looks like it addresses all your requirements, and is free :

http://www.todo-backup.com/products/home/free-backup-software.htm

Comment: +1 for EASEUS.  I have used it for a year or so and even had to restore from a disk image.  No problems...seems to work great.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to do a lot of this by running your systems as virtual machines.  Bear with me. Windows 7 allows you to boot from a VHD.  That would allow you to backup the disk as a single file, allow you to snapshot it and you could boot form a previous version if there was a problem.

On top of that, there are programs allow you to open VHDs to access files.

Comment: +1 informative. that would however necessitate reinstallation of windows/migration of current installations and would not be suitable in my case.

Comment: Not necessary. You can use disk2vhd from: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ee656415.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Not free, but [Rebit](http://rebit.com/) does what you ask- Disclosure: I work for Rebit.